# Different HTML markup for similar menus

Tags: menus, html

I am building a navigation with two menus. I have them registered:

```
  register_nav_menus([
      'contents_navigation' => __('Navegación contenidos', 'prr'),
      'insti-navigation' => __( 'Navegación institucional', 'prr' )
  ]);
```

And I have this code in the header template to output HTML:

```
wp_nav_menu([
    'theme_location' => 'insti_navigation', 
    'menu_class' => 'nav insti'
]);
wp_nav_menu([
    'theme_location' => 'contents_navigation',
    'menu_class' => 'nav cont'
]);
```

I think the output should be the same for both, but `contents_navigation` output ID in the UL and a lot of classes more than `insti_navigation`:

```
<div class="nav insti">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-19">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/amigos/">Amigos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-22">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/contacto/">Contacto</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-28">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/documentacion/">Documentación</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-26">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/iniciativas/">Iniciativas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-8">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/introduccion/">Introducción</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-24">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/noticias/">Noticias</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-30">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/que-opinan/">Qué opinan</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-navegacion-contenidos-container">
    <ul id="menu-navegacion-contenidos" class="nav cont">
        <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/que-opinan/">Qué opinan</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/documentacion/">Documentación</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/iniciativas/">Iniciativas</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43">
            <a href="//localhost:3000/noticias/">Noticias</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Why the markup is different between these two menus?

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the code, there was a typo:

`insti-navigation` instead `insti_navigation` in the register function.

Sorry for the noise.